# Showing that $\{x \in X: \sup_n\sum_{i=0}^n f(T^i(x)) = \infty\}$ is a $T$ invariant set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $(X, \sigma, \mu)$ be a probability space, $T:X\to X$ a $\mu$-invariant map and $f\in L^1(\mu)$. Define $A := \{x \in X: \sup_n\sum_{i=0}^n f(T^i(x)) = \infty\}$. I would like to conclude that $A$ is $T$ invariant, i.e. that $T^{-1}(A) = A$. Then any $x\in A$ would satisfy $T(x) \in A$, i.e. that

$$\sup_n\sum_{i=0}^n f(T^{i+1}(x)) = \sup_{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}f(T^i(x)) = \infty$$

But what if $f(x) = \infty$, $|f(y)| < \infty$ for all $y\in X\setminus \{x\}$ and $f$ is finite enough along the orbit $T^i(x), i\in \mathbb{N}$ that $\sup_n\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(T^i(x)) < \infty$ and $\mu(\{x\}) = 0$? In this case $T(x)\not\in A$ which would imply that $A$ is not $T$ invariant.

The claim that $A$ is $T$ invariant occurs in the book *Introduction to Moden Theory of Dynamical Systems* by Anatole Katok and Boris Hasselblatt, p. 136, the proof of Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem

Comment: Is $f(x)=\infty$ allowed in $L^1(\mu)?$

Comment: I believe that in this context, invariant means $\mu$-a.s invariant. Meaning that $\mu(A \triangle T^{-1}(A)) = 0.$ Otherwise, you can easily come up with counter-examples. Observe that the def of $A$ depends on the choice of the representing $f$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I suppose if $\mu(\{x\}) = 0$. That is $f\in L^1(\mu)$ iff $\int_X|f(x)|d\mu(x) < \infty$.

Comment: @MatheusManzatto Nice observation! This could very well be the case.